# Томатис-терапия — с прописной или строчной буквы?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

**Томатис-терапия** пишется с большой или маленькой буквы?
(Вроде как по фамилии ученого…)

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже считаю, что с прописной, потому что это метод Томатиса. Побегала по сайтам, нашла - точно с большой: Томатис-терапия.

https://golmozg.ru/lechenie/tomatis-terapiya.html